# At least one of these variables is equal to something

Tags: notation

I have two variables $a$ and $b$, at least one of these variables must be equal to some constant, call it $c$.

If $a$ = $c$, then $b$ could be anything, including $c$.
Or, if $b$ = $c$, then $a$ could be anything, including $c$.

Do I write that as such: $\exists (a,b) = 0$?

I suspect that isn't correct.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please refine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$
a=c\; \vee\, b=c.
$$